# snappy wkhtmltopdf wrapper send generated html file to browser

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I googled like a mole, but can´t find the right way to go.

I´m creating a PDF with the WKHTMLTOPDF Wrapper Snappy.

How can I send the pdf generated with the method generateFromHtml straight to the Browser?
Thats what I´m trying to do:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->generateFromHtml($contents);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use the `getOutput/getOutputFromHtml` methods to return the PDF as a string, `generate/generateFromHtml` will save the PDF to a file and not return anything.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
// Remove the next line to let the browser display the PDF
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($contents);
```

[Snappy GeneratorInterface and documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/blob/master/src/Knp/Snappy/GeneratorInterface.php)

- **Save PDF of URL `$input` to file `$output`**
  *generate($input, $output, array $options = array(), $overwrite =
     false)*
- **Save PDF of HTML `$html` to file `$output`**
  *generateFromHtml($html, $output, array $options = array(), $overwrite = false)*
- **Return PDF of URL `$input` as string**
  *getOutput($input, array $options = array())*
- **Return PDF of HTML `$html` as string**
  *getOutputFromHtml($html, array $options = array())*