# the Binary is not set for in snappy wrapper for wkhtmltopdf in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation, knp-snappy

How to use snappy library with codeigniter.

1. i've installed and have it in my libraries folder .
   like

   require_once dirname(**FILE**) . '/snappy/vendor/autoload.php';
   use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

   ```
    class wkhtmltopdf extends Pdf
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }
   ```

2 ) then in contoller i've load it through function __construct()

```
$this->load->library('wkhtmltopdf');
```

3. in one of my controller i set binary like

   $snappy = new wkhtmltopdf(""C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"");

and try it
4 )

```
echo $snappy->getOutput(array('http://www.google.com.pk'));
```

but the below error come.

but it thrown an error.
Type: LogicException

Message: You must define a binary prior to conversion.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\reporting-new-icn-huge-changes\application\libraries\snappy\vendor\knplabs\knp-snappy\src\Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator.php

Anybody have implemented wkhtmltopdf in codeignter through any method will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After download the library using Composer.

```
$ composer require knplabs/knp-snappy
```

Add it in the Library folder and give the path for the autoload.php

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."application/libraries/snappy/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Adjust the above path and outside of the Controller class

```
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf; # at the top of the controller
```

## this is the Path to Binary file and in the Linux servers adjust it as given with the help of github.com/KnpLabs/snappy

#& inside the controller function

```
{
$snappy = new Pdf("\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"");

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $snappy->setOption('page-width', '188mm');
echo $snappy->setOption('page-height', '100mm');
# these options are Optional there are a lot of other options.
#Can check more options Here https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

echo $snappy->getOutput($url);
#OR in case of you want the HTML to put directly open in the Browser.

echo $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html);
#OR 
echo $snappy->generateFromHtml('<p>Some content</p>', 'test.pdf');
# this test.pdf will be saved in hte Codeigniter directory
}
```

[To get out put directly see this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105433/snappy-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper-send-generated-html-file-to-browser)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haagb.png)

```html
<img src= "https://i.stack.imgur.com/haagb.png">
```

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html   the Exe file in windows and the same type of executable requires for Linux, Amazon etc. given on that page.
further requires this library which is wrapper used to set settings, output and other stuff etc.
https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy > this can be installed using git commands in vendor folder